# Why would && return true for non-intersecting bounding boxes?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

```
select ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[37.75074414,-57.54978713],[37.748904483,-57.558230569],[37.744033941,-57.566318698],[37.736317969,-57.573740353],[37.726051981,-57.580209837],[37.71363017,-57.585477965],[37.699530409,-57.589341734],[37.68429581,-57.591652205],[37.668513658,-57.592320296],[37.652792564,-57.591320254],[37.637738755,-57.58869065],[37.623932455,-57.584532883],[37.611905332,-57.579007225],[37.602119892,-57.572326588],[37.594951666,-57.564748258],[37.590674851,-57.556563919],[37.589451974,-57.54808838],[37.591327923,-57.539647429],[37.596228546,-57.531565304],[37.603963807,-57.524152253],[37.614235355,-57.517692666],[37.626648151,-57.51243422],[37.640725695,-57.508578444],[37.655928257,-57.506273061],[37.671673429,-57.505606376],[37.687358229,-57.506603931],[37.702381958,-57.509227531],[37.716168969,-57.513376693],[37.728190532,-57.518892455],[37.737984986,-57.525563409],[37.74517543,-57.533133747],[37.749484283,-57.541312998],[37.75074414,-57.54978713]]]}')::geography
&&
(select ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Point","coordinates":[37.75870282438855,-122.44584844354561]}}')::geography)
```

By looking at the their position on the map not sure why `&&` returns `true`? `ST_Intersects` returns `false`. Any explanation on this would solidify my understanding. I am still new to PostGIS.

Here's how the look on the map:

[image]

Comment: There’s something funny going on with your latitudes — where is -122° supposed to be?

Comment: ah thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using latitudes greater than +-90, PostGIS will either error out, truncate, go back from the pole or go across the pole. Beside throwing an error, I have yet to see a usefulness for these behaviors.

==> sanitize your data.

```sql
select st_asText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Point","coordinates":[37.75870282438855,-122.44584844354561]}}')::geography);
NOTICE:  Coordinate values were coerced into range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY
                  st_astext
----------------------------------------------
 POINT(37.75870282438855 -57.554151556454386)
```